# Non RBAC User Roles and Permissions System: checking the user's City

Tags: asp.net-membership, rbac

We are currently **designing** a **User Roles and Permissions System** in our web application (ASP.NET), and it seems that we have several **cases** that **do no fit** within the classical **Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)**. I will post several questions, each devoted to a particular case, this being the first post.

We have the following **case**: not to allow a user view a certain page if the user lives in a particular city. This is a simple case that is coded in the following way:

`if (User.City == “Moscow”)

// Allow the user to view the page.

else

// Do not allow the user to view this page.`

Though this case is very simple and straightforward, it has nothing to do with the RBAC.

On StackOverflow, someone called this an **Attribute-based Access Control**.

Under the classical RBAC, it seems that this case should be designed like this: introduce a **permission “City where the person lives”**, this permission will have a property City. Then create a role, add a permission of type “City = Moscow” to it and the assign the role to the user. Looks extremely **cumbersome**.

**The question is** whether it is acceptable to introduce such non-RBAC approaches to our permissions system – does that break the design or not?

This might seem a primitive question, but we found that most applications use pure RBAC, and we started to think that we might be doing something wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: See my answer to your other question - the issues are the same. I am voting to close this as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839819/non-rbac-user-roles-and-permissions-system-a-role-with-properties. No offense intended.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non RBAC User Roles and Permissions System: a role with properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839819/non-rbac-user-roles-and-permissions-system-a-role-with-properties)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a nice case for an atribute based access control. However, if you don't mind looking at a PHP implementation, Zend Framework has a role based access control that uses assertions to solve more special cases:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html

A standard rule would allow a role to do an action on a resource. A fourth parameter allows the rule only to apply when some condition is met. In pseudocode:

```
allow(member, view, page) // standard
allow(member, view, page, userLivesInMoscow) // assertion used
```

The assertion is an object that is passed the user. It has a method that checks whether the assertion is met:

```
interface Assertion
 bool public function assert()

class UserLivesIn implements Assertion
 public function UserLivesIn(User, City) ...
 // implementation of assert method comes here
```

This is a way of implementing what you need.

Comment: uh... if you were working in a Linux,PHP environment and had a problem and someone suggested that perhaps it would be easier to solve in an ASP.Net/C#/Windows environment, what would your impression be?

Comment: @code poet I don't suggest solving it in another environment. I'm only pointing to an example solution in another environment that can be used as inspiration to port to the current environment. 'Looking at' != 'implementing with'.

Comment: ok, point taken. note: no downvote. But the reality of the situation is that the ASP.Net membership/roles infrastructure does not lend itself to this type of extension and consideration there of would require redesign, reimplementation of the entire security infrastructure.